# Perform simple IO in Haskeline, inside InputT monad, without having to resort to unsafePerformIO

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskeline

Given the proof of concept code below I'd like to be able to somehow perform my `foo` function with the ability to output the string `Paul!` and the possibility of getting its return value inside the `InputT` monad-transformer without using `unsafePerformIO` to remove the IO wrapper after `runExceptT`.

```
import Control.Monad.Except

import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import System.Console.Haskeline


type ErrorWithIO = ExceptT String IO


foo :: String -> ErrorWithIO String
foo "paul" = do liftIO $ putStrLn "Paul!"
                return "OK!"
foo _ = throwError "ERROR!"


runRepl :: IO ()
runRepl = runInputT defaultSettings $ loop


loop :: InputT IO ()
loop = do
    line <- getInputLine "> "
    case line of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just input -> do return $ putStrLn "asd"
                         case unsafePerformIO $ runExceptT $ foo input of
                             Left err -> outputStrLn err >> loop
                             Right res -> do
                                 x <- outputStrLn . show $ res
                                 loop




main :: IO ()
main = runRepl >> putStrLn "Goodbye!"
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `InputT IO` is a `MonadIO`, you can use `liftIO` with this type:

```
liftIO :: IO a -> InputT IO a
```

So,

```
do ...
   x <- liftIO $ runExceptT $ foo input
   case x of
     Left err  -> ...
     Right res -> ...
```

Alternatively, use `Control.Monad.Trans.lift` instead.

Comment: I already tried this solution, but I get a compilation error: `No instance for (MonadIO (InputT IO))
      arising from a use of ‘liftIO’`

Comment: The same for the simple `lift` solution: `No instance for (MonadTrans InputT) arising from a use of ‘lift’`

Comment: @Paul Surprising... here I have such an instance. Maybe you need to `import Control.Monad.IO.Class` ?

Comment: @Paul What version of Haskeline are you using? Do you have multiple versions of some packages installed? This looks like a cabal issue.

Comment: @Paul IIRC (a big if), I had the "No instance..." errors issue and it appeared after I installed a different Cabal package. Try re-installing the Haskeline package through Cabal (I think there might be a `--reinstall` option) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Paul haskeline 0.7.1.3 here, BTW

Comment: @Paul I just checked my notes and the "No instance..." error you were getting was what I was getting. I worked out that it had started happening after I'd installed the Lens library, and that re-installing the Haskeline library fixed the problem.

Comment: @chi, The problem is solved, I tried reinstalling haskeline and hiding an older version of it (I somehow wound up having two of them, 0.7.1.2 and 0.7.1.3). This seemed to do the trick.