# unwrap getInputLine result from Input

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, haskeline

I'm getting a result from `getInputline`, whose type is:

```
(MonadException m) => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
```

I'd like to get just the `Maybe String` part. I'm well aware that in general there is no way to strip a monad, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8569332/165753) (and other answers in the same question). However, since I'm doing it inside an `InputT`, I guess it's possible, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28053686/165753). However, I can't just use `liftIO`, as the answer suggests, since the `IO` is inside a `StateT`.

```
loop :: Counter -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()    
loop c = do
        minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c
        case minput of
          Nothing -> outputStrLn "Goodbye."
          Just input -> (process' c input) >> loop c      

getLineIO :: (MonadException m) => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
getLineIO ios = do
    s <- liftIO ios
    getInputLine s

process' :: Counter -> String -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
[...]
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Main.hs:81:15:
    No instance for (MonadException (StateT [String] IO))
      arising from a use of ‘getLineIO’
    In the expression: getLineIO
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c
    In the expression:
      do { minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c;
           case minput of {
             Nothing -> outputStrLn "Goodbye."
             Just input -> (process' c input) >> loop c } }
```

If I remove `getLineIO` and use `getInputLine` directly, as per @chepner's advice:

```
loop :: Counter -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
loop c = do
    minput <- (in_ps1 c) >>= getInputLine
    case minput of
      Nothing -> outputStrLn "Goodbye."
      Just input -> (process' c input) >> loop c
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Main.hs:81:16:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘InputT (StateT [String] IO)’
    Expected type: InputT (StateT [String] IO) String
      Actual type: IO String
    In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘(in_ps1 c)’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: minput <- (in_ps1 c) >>= getInputLine
```

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/dimidd/write-you-a-haskell/blob/master/chapter4/untyped/Main.hs), and explanations about what I'm trying to do can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930204/combining-statet-with-inputt/).

Comment: Yes, `liftIO` is `liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a`, and `getLineIO` is a wrapper. The only difference that it takes an argument of `IO String` instead of `getInputLine`'s regular `String`. How would you suggest to unwrap it?

Comment: If `getInputLine` just takes a regular string, then `getLineIO ios = ios >>= getInputLine`. You don't need `lift`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I'm following you. Please see the updated question, is that what you had in mind?